# How to update a PostgreSQL database without downtime?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

We have designed a process that:

- takes a massive 600MB csv file that contains 1.3 millions entries (healthcare professional)
- a new file is published every day with the changes of the day , and the changes are

> new doctors can be found between two exports

> dead doctors are removed between two exports

- we have an nice ETL process to import to find the flat file, process, import it into a nice PostgreSQL database.
- the process takes around 40 minutes to process and update the PostgreSQL database
- we have a NestJS backend that expose API in order for a user to find any sort of data contained in the flat files.

Question :
What would be the best implementation to avoid a 40 minutes downtime of our API because of the duration of the transformation and import of the flat file every day ?

The reason we want to avoid any downtime is :
Our healthcare professional API expose a "Unique Id" that is used for authentication, if the API is down 40 minutes so is our authentication process.

Comment: Does the flatfile have to loaded directly in the destination table used by the authentication? Or could it be loaded into a temporary table, which can then be merged into the destination table?

Comment: Do you have to stop the API while this runs? Why not just progress it and add/remove?

Comment: @LukStorms:
I was thinking about your solution, do you know how fast is the merge process ? 

The PostgreSQL process is hosted on a system with very fast storage (raid 5 of SAS 12G SAS drive), more than 100 000 iops.

I expect the duration of the merge to be very sensitive of the storage.

Comment: @Jeppe:
I believe you are also right, it appears the API can still run during the update of the database.

As I am a little bit paranoid, I am wondering about the following case:
> a doctor is logged in
> he is using our platform for 2 hours
> some doctors can be removed from the database because a court has decided they are not allowed to practice as a doctor for the next 2 years
> the doctor has an open session ... but during the DB update process, his account is disabled

Comment: > a way I can imagine to mitigate this "unlikely" event is to set an "autologout" process.
> after attempting to log again, the new status of this doctor is applied and the connection would be refused

Comment: Well, isn't that an edge case that can happen anyways? Maybe you could show your code that takes 40 minutes to run. Maybe an optimization can be applied?

Comment: As for the autologout, I would recommend looking into using GraphQL subscriptions. The general idea being that your frontend subscribes to changes to the database; if the status of a doctor changes, your frontend could be notified right away via the subscription

Comment: @Kynes Sorry, but that's impossible to estimate for an outsider.  Also depends on how. Via SQL upserts / MERGE statement? Via some functionality from the ETL?  You'd have to test to find out.